# Single API Platform for multiple cryptocurrency?

Tags: api, altcoin, litecoin, trading, currencies

I am wondering for a single API platform where i will be able to trade for below 5 crypto currency :

1) Bitcoin
2) Litecoin
3) Ethereum
4) Dash
5) Monero

So, are you guys supporting all these in 1 packet ??

Hope your asap revert,

Answer (score 0):

Kraken deals in all of these. You can find the API at api.kraken.com

Answer (score 0):

A lot of cryptoexchanges allow trading with currencies you're interesting with.
Here is a short list of them
1. Poloniex, https://poloniex.com/support/api/
2. Bitfinex, https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs
3. Bittrex, https://bittrex.com/home/api

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider [HitBTC API](https://api.hitbtc.com/).
I am also investigating this, it has 2 interfaces: REST and WebSocket, I went with WebSocket. You can get the list of symbols traded, list of all currencies, request/subscribe to ticker, candles, trades (public data). On the private side, you can create/modify/cancel orders, subscribe to notifications for orders (which gets you notifications about the trades for your order too), request the positions you have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many exchanges with those currencies which contain an API, or you can use pre-built API wrappers depending on your preferred language. I am including my answer from a previous post here, for API's/wrappers for crypto currency trading:

1. [CCXT is a python/javascript library with the functionality](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) you request. You can then trade with any exchange you'd like such as Binance, Poloniex, etc. There are commands for actions you would like to perform, such as placing an order, and you write additional code for your 'bot' to determine when to buy/sell.
2. [Gekko is a similar open source library for Node](https://gekko.wizb.it/) with similar functionality for trading cryptocurrencies among varying exchanges.